# Staff allocation in linear optimazation problem over a year (python/elasticsearch/gurobi

Tags: pandas, dataframe, elasticsearch, gurobi

i have a problem with a staff allocation system. I have demand data for a year with hourly demand of each staff member. I need to use agregations in elastic search to et the amount of staff i need in this year, when they can work maximum a 5 hour shift a day. I struggle with seperating the year into days, and than optimize it with a minimization of staff use. Would be amazing if someone could help me. Thank you very much.

Andy

I tried to use lasticsearch aggregations, to find the demand per hour. and i could find the demand per day. but i dont know how i can combine these 2.

Comment: Please show what you've done so far and where it itches... Always easier to not start from a blank slate. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.